# xalan command line passing params to xslt

Tags: bash, xslt, parameters, xslt-1.0, xalan

I am trying to do a command line processing of xml with xslt by using xalan command line:

(http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xalan.1.html)

### Command Used :

```
xalan -q -param name_param 'something relevant' -xsl use.xsl -in use.xml
```

### Xalan version used :

```
Xalan version 1.11.0
Xerces version 3.2.0
```

### Trial and Error

I have tried single quotes and double quotes in the command
and tried accessing the param in xslt as  but still I am not able to access the params I pass in the command line

I want to be able to use the parameters passed inside the use.xsl for processing the use.xml

Comment: Does your XSLT have a global `<xsl:param name="name_param"/>`? What exactly is the result when you say you are "not able to access the params"?

Answer (score 2):

http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-c/usagepatterns.html#xalantransformer says "The Xalan command line utility currently supports only a text string value for a top-level stylesheet parameter. The single quotes are required to identify a text string value." and "If the string expression includes spaces or other characters that the shell intercepts, first enclose the string in single quotes so Xalan-C++ interprets it as a string expression, and then enclose the resulting string in double quotes so the shell interprets it as a single argument." and gives an example `Xalan -p param1 "'string expression'"foo.xml foo.xsl`. I haven't tested that but it is too long to fit into a comment so posting as an answer.

Comment: Excellent findings!